# Dedupe SQL Server Table [stored procedure]

Tags: sql, sql-server, deduplication

I'm looking to dedupe a table using a stored procedure. There is no 1 column that is unique, so I'd have to combine 2 or more columns to get a unique identifier. ID column is identity int, but is generated by sql automatically at the time data is imported. I need to somehow combine 2 or more columns excluding ID column to get a unique identifier so I can strip out anything that's duplicated.

From there I figured it would make the most sense to do the following [correct me if my approach is wrong].

1. create temp table
2. query table using dedupe logic
3. import query results into new temp table
4. drop original [or delete contents?]
5. recreate original[or repopulate?] import data from temp
6. drop temp table

I have the following columns. I think sessionid+callflow is unique.

sessionid, 
legid, 
dialednumber, 
callerid, 
calldatetime, 
dayofweek, 
hourofday, 
end_type, 
callduration, 
callorder, 
callflow, 
ID,  [pk]
origin

Comment: See if this helps: http://codecorner.galanter.net/2011/02/02/tsql-remove-duplicate-records/

Comment: It's just a delete with join on two or more columns, most of the de-dupe answers on here should be applicable.

Comment: Yes, the other questions do answer mine. Should I delete this?